# Cognos: Case Statement where Data X can equal Multiple Values

Tags: case, cognos

I am trying to create an exceptions report and I have values that can have multiple correct roles. THE CASE statement solves in order so they always show in the exceptions. For Example my Case Statement looks like this:

```
CASE 
WHEN [DATA 1] = 1 THEN ('A')
WHEN [DATA 1] = 2 THEN ('B')
WHEN [DATA 1] = 2 THEN ('C')

ELSE ('HELP')
END
```

WHEN [DATA 1] = 2 THEN I would be ok with the value Being B or C. I am comparing this to another Data Item that contains the A,B,C value. When [DATA 1] = 2 and has value C populated it shows on the exceptions report because the case statement solves in order and shows it must Equal B. What is the best alternative?

Comment: Can you clarify? I've read the question several times and don't quite understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I have one column that has the actual values that I want to compare to. Then I want to create another column that has what thier value should be, some users can have multiple values. If Data 1 = 2 THEN it could be A or B. When I vlaidate against the column that has the actual values it only validates aganist the first value not aganist the 2 option. Does this help?

Comment: Not really. I believe you just restated your original question. You are right that your third WHEN statement will never be evaluated when Data 1 = 2. What I'm not sure of is why you would want it to. An outline of what you have and what you are trying to produce would be helpful.